# Ceiling fan wire if confusion

Tags: wiring, ceiling, ceiling-fan

I’m trying to install a new ceiling fan. I’m having a bunch of difficulties. There are two wall switches that control the lights. Out of the ceiling there are 5 wires a ground bare copper 3 white one black.

One of the white and the Black was twisted together. So when I installed the fan I connected the black and blue from the fan to the white and black from the ceiling. I then connected the two whites to the white from the fan and then  the grounds.  When I turn the lights on it blows the circuit. To compound things I didn’t realize the remote has to wired in so I will try to put that in.

---

Let me clarify it is confusing there’s I think I missed a few.

I climbed in the attic. There are two red 3 black 3 white  two black  were white nutted together two red were wire nuted together. Leaving 3 white 1 black 3 green  I’m not concerned with the green. One black and one white were twisted together. So I think the red and black nuted together is a feed going to other lights.

The two switches are for the fan lights one by the bed one by the door the are unions in the attic I believe with on wire coming in.  I got new fan with lower power draw but just hooked thought all was good it was running with light on but when I cleaned hit the switch to turn the light off the fuse popped I’m confused have pictures this time I don’t quite get the black and white twisted together.

[image]

[image]

Comment: *There are two wall switches that control the lights.* Do you mean there are other lights besides the box where you are trying to install the fan?

Comment: *One of the white and the Black was twisted together.* Were the other wires just hanging there?

Comment: *Ok so I’m trying to install a new ceiling fan.* What was there before? A light? A fan? Was it working?

Comment: Don't guess! You have to figure out where every wire is connected and what it is for. Then you can attach new stuff.

Comment: Are you wedded to the remote that came with your fan?